# Символьные примитивы в HTML-коде, представленном в кодировке UTF-8

Tags: html, utf-8

Для некоторых символов, не входящих в «базовый» набор ASCII, в HTML существуют специальные символьные примитивы - например, `&copy;` для символа `©`.

Однако, если страницы сайта отдаются в кодировке UTF-8 (или UTF-16), использовать примитивы необязательно - можно просто писать в HTML-коде `©`.

Какие есть соображения за и против? На ум приходит два аргумента:

- обратная совместимость: если HTML с кодом `&copy;` будет почему-то сохранён в однобайтной кодировке (cp1251 / windows-1251 и т.п.), ничего не изменится, а если в однобайтную кодировку попробовать экспортировать символ `©` - получится кракозябра;
- наглядность: актуально для пробельных (`&nbsp;`, `&thinsp;`), невидимых (`&shy;`) или очень похожих визуально (`&minus;`, `&ndash;`, `&mdash;`, `&oline;`, ...) символов - так легче отличить один символ «тире» от другого, чуть длиннее/короче.

Аргументов за повсеместное использование в коде «готовых» символов вместо символьных примитив как-то не придумывается. Что ещё я упустил?

Comment: Однобайтные кодировки — зло, так что обратной совместимостью с ними можно наверное пожертовать.

Comment: @VladD можно, если это даст какие-то преимущества. Жертвовать просто ради жертвы - это как-то неконструктивно.

Comment: Насчет символа `©` вы неправы, это ascii символ 0xA9.

Comment: @zenden2k не ANSI а ASCII, моя вина, исправил

Comment: @zenden2k если я правильно понимаю, символ 0xA9 `©` входит в расширенный набор символов (ANSI) и не может быть представлен чистым ASCII, который RFC 20 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc20)

Comment: Да, я ошибся. Тем не менее, он прекрасно сохраняется в кодировке windows-1251.

Comment: Окей, значит академически мой пример корректен, хотя и не слишком актуален в реальной жизни (потому что cp1251 - это не ASCII, а чистый ASCII в мире web встречается редко).

Comment: "почему-то сохранён в однобайтной кодировке" - это не обратная совместимость, это баг. С таким же успехом можно агитировать за использование транслита, чтобы читалось там где нет русских шрифтов. Ну и UTF-8 использующий ASCII набор символов собственно от него ничем отличатся не будет (если только не присутствует BOM).